# React reset select options when depending on the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, select

I have a Select tag which allows the user to pick between 2-7 people,
I also have a onChange event where it saves that number to the state.
After that, it'll call the updateMenuSelect function and render x amount of select tags. The problem is that i want each option in the updateMenuSelect, to be Meal #X, not the previously selected item.

```
 updateMenuSelect() {
    const menuSelector = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.personCount; i++) {
      menuSelector.push(
        <div>
          <select onChange={this.addMeal} name={i}>
            <option value={0} selected>
              Meal #{i + 1}
            </option>
            <option value={15}>Cheesy Stuffed BBQ Pork Burgers</option>
            <option value={17}>Tex-Mex Cheese-Stuffed Burgers</option>
            <option value={20}>Fiesta Chicken Tacos</option>
            <option value={24}>Apricot Balsamic-Glazed Pork Tenderloin</option>
            <option value={15}>Lemon Pepper Chicken Linguine</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return <div>{menuSelector}</div>;
  }
```

For example, say i pick 3 people, it'll then render 3 selections with same options in each one. If for all 3, i pick "Fiesta Chicken Tacos" and then I update the amount of people to 6, it'll render 6 select tags, but with the first 3 still having "Fiesta Chicken Tacos" in it. How can i make it so the text in the options resets?
I have a working react sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/8z20mnkk38

Comment: i would add a wrapper component, which sends a callback, and on change trigger callback, and make wrapper rerender all the selects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the existing options are re-used. This happens because you do not specify a key that signifies that these are new select boxes.

The simplest approach would be to add a `key` to the outer `div` which depends on the count of select boxes and the actual index of each select.

so changing

```
menuSelector.push(
    <div>
```

to

```
menuSelector.push(
    <div key={`${i}-${this.state.personCount}`}>
```

will fix the problem.

Updated demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/q868qyrx16

Answer (score 2):

If you put the selected option for each `<select>` into the state, then you can reset them all in the `changedPersonCount` method.

I've updated your sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/6w54qj2y2z

---

#### Explanation of what I changed

Added selected options to state:

```
this.state = {
  personCount: 0,
  selectedOptions: {}
};
```

Implemented that addMeal function (feel free to modify this to include whatever functionality you wanted it to also do when they selected an option)

```
addMeal = (index, value) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      selectedOptions: { ...prevState.selectedOptions, [index]: value }
    }));
};
```

Get the selected value for each `<select>` in the loop

```
...
for (let i = 0; i < this.state.personCount; i++) {
    const selectedValue = this.state.selectedOptions[i] || 0;
...
```

Change the `<select>` to use the value from state, and call addMeal with parameters on change

```
<select
    onChange={e => {
      this.addMeal(i, e.target.value);
    }}
    name={i}
    value={selectedValue}
 >
```

Removed `selected` attribute from default `<option>`

```
<option value={0}>Meal #{i + 1}</option>
```